# Wordpress - is category dont works

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I'm new to wordpress, I'm trying to display custom html divs for one category (with ID 7). So this is my code..

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php is_category( '7' ); ?>
        <?php echo 'test'; ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <div class="latest-posts">
                    <div class="latest-posts-info">
                    <div class="title"><h1><?php the_title(); ?><h1></div>
                    <div class="text">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more">Read more...</a>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="latest-posts-img">
                    <?php //echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <?php custom_get_post_attachments(get_the_ID(), $__width, $__height, get_the_title()); ?>                   
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
        </article>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <div class="content">
        <p class="not-found-p">No articles found!</p>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

It should display TEST for that category, but it doesnt. Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `is_category()` returns true or false. use it in a conditional statement.

Answer (score 2):

`is_category` returns a boolean if you're in the appropriate category. You're simply calling it in your code - you need to wrap it in an if statement instead:

```
if (is_category('7')) {
    echo 'TEST';
}
```

The documentation for WordPress is very comprehensive, and well worth a read through:
[Codex entry for `is_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)